# AWS EC2 generic suspect

Tags: email, amazon-ec2, dns

All my e-mails from aws plesk instances are going to gmail spam and been reject by outlook

Making a test in app.glockapps.com I discovered that my NEW instances and elastic IP is in black list of this site https://matrix.spfbl.net/3.209.102.205 it says that my rDNS ec2-3-209-102-205.compute-1.amazonaws.com is generic

I config my DNS on registro.br

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure reverse DNS, which means the IP address should resolve to the domain you are using for sending emails.

You would be required to create `PTR record` for your domain with the used IP address. This will fix the issue of reverse DNS being generic.

For AWS you need to fill this form https://aws.amazon.com/forms/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request

Comment: my domain provider (registro br) doesn't have an option for PTR record, but I discovered this link to change hostname on amazon https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-hostname.html and another form that I cant find to request changing hostname

Comment: https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request this form you can fill for reverse dns setup on ec2 instance.